# Why FieldByFieldComparator from assertJ doesn't work?

Tags: java, comparator, bigdecimal, assertj

I tried to use FieldByFieldComparator from AssertJ when comparing two lists of JavaBeans elements with BigDecimals fields and it doesn't work.
 When I compare these two BigDecimals (eg. 1.00 and 1.000000), using default BigDecimal comparator, assertion not fail (because these are equal by comparing to).

I also wrote my own BeansFieldByFieldComparator, and it works, but I wonder if it was necessary because such comparator is included in AssertJ, maybe I use it in a wrong way ? but everything indicates that I'm right - it doesn't work.

JavaBean code:

```
@Value
public static class Foo {
    BigDecimal bar;
}
```

Assertion that doesn't work:

```
assertThat(asList(new Foo(new BigDecimal("1.000"))))
.usingFieldByFieldElementComparator()
.containsOnlyElementsOf(asList(new Foo(new BigDecimal("1.0000000"))));
```

Why FieldByFieldComparator doesn't work? Thanks in advance for any help : )

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that it uses the `BigDecimal` `equals` method to compare `bar` fields and [BigDecimal's equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) differentiate `2.0` from `2.00` ([usingFieldByFieldElementComparator](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#usingFieldByFieldElementComparator--) javadoc states that fields are compared with `equals`).

To get you assertion to pass, you can specify how the assertion should compare `BigDecimal` with `usingComparatorForType`, ex:

```
assertThat(asList(new Foo(new BigDecimal("1.000"))))
         .usingFieldByFieldElementComparator()
         .usingComparatorForType(BIG_DECIMAL_COMPARATOR, BigDecimal.class)
         .containsOnlyElementsOf(asList(new Foo(new BigDecimal("1.0000000"))));
```

where `BIG_DECIMAL_COMPARATOR` is a `Comparator<BigDecimal>` implemented by calling BigDecimal's [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) method, see [`org.assertj.core.util.BigDecimalComparator`](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/blob/cc178abc5871bc34525113550373ffd90e303034/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/util/BigDecimalComparator.java).

Comment: Thank you so much !

Now I see, I thought that it uses compareTo, for every field, instead of equals. Next time I should read javadoc more deeply ;)